# WordPress Sidebar on single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, sidebar

So, my sidebar is working just fine on my blog page: beta.cleantelligent.com/blog
However, when you click a single post, I'd like that same sidebar to show up.

I am assuming this would be under single.php, right? That code is listed below. Let me know if you need any other code and I'll post it here.

I have the 'blog' sidebar in my page attributes on the Edit Page in Wordpress, but it's just not being recognized by the template, I guess?

Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<?php 
get_header(); ?>
<div class="blackbar">
<div class='bbw'>
Blog
</div>
</div>
<div class='cont-wrap'>

<div id="primary">
    <?php
$post_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_name = $post_obj->post_name;
if($post_name == 'blog'){
    echo 'Blog';
}else{
    $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    echo $parent_title;
}
?>
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'archive' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
```

The blog page is using index.php

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div class="blackbar">
<div class='bbw'>
<?php
$post_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_name = $post_obj->post_name;
if($post_name == 'blog'){
    echo 'Blog';
}else{
    $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    echo $parent_title;
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cont-wrap'>
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' ); ?>



                <?php comments_template( '', false ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>

</div><!-- #main -->
```

Here is my sidebar.php:

```
<?php

$options = twentyeleven_get_theme_options();
$current_layout = $options['theme_layout'];
$nav = sb_get_page_nav($post);
if ( 'content' != $current_layout ) :
?>
<img class="sidebar-top" src='<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/sidebar-top.png' />
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php
        $post_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $post_name = $post_obj->post_name;
        $title = 'cs-' . $post_name; 
        ?>
    <?php
        if($post_name == 'news-events'){
            if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-web' ) ) :
            endif;
        }
    ?>

    <?php if(!$nav['no_nav']) { ?>
        <div class="SimpleSideNav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('container_id' => 'left-navigation','menu' => $nav['title'])); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>


    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-all' ) ) : ?>
    <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    <?php /*
    <nav id="left-nav">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <?php if(!$nav['no_nav']) {
                wp_nav_menu(array('container_id' => 'left-navigation','menu' => $nav['title']));
            } ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
        */ ?>

        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( $title ) ) : ?>
        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
        <img class="sidebar-bot" src='<?php     bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/sidebar-bot.png' />
    </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->

<?php endif; 
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
if($parent_title == 'Tour'){
echo"
<script>
jQuery('.w-1').hide();
</script>
";
}
?>
```

Comment: which template is used by the blog ?

Comment: I put my sidebar in the header and it shows up on every page, but I am using `position:fixed` so I don't know if you need it where you have it for positioning

Comment: the blog is using index.php

Comment: @JCKnoell look in the index.php... What does it have for <?php get_sidebar(); ?>  Is it like that, or does it have something inbetween the ( )

Comment: @JCKnoell add your index.php code here

Comment: It's blank. There is no name listed in either one.I just added the index.php code above.

Comment: @JCKnoell if these two are same, then there is something in sidebar.php file. Can you add that ?

Comment: I've added sidebar.php above

Comment: @JCKnoell  your sidebar is loading. if you check with the html you can see that the top image is loaded. It is not loading below part. Can you check what is the output of $nav = sb_get_page_nav($post);

Comment: @Sabari But that's just the image that's included with every sidebar, right? The actual links and content isn't loading... "Can you check what is the output of $nav = sb_get_page_nav($post);" I don't really know what that means... :S

Comment: Has this question been buried, or is everyone stumped? :)

Comment: Well, this is resolved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a brand new sidebar under sidebar-blog.php and redirecting my templates to it.